# Variable in jQuery seems not working in combination with php

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress

The file is within .php ext and it's in the WordPress template page. When I put variable to get URI to $.post request it just doesn't work. However, if I replace vurl with absolute url, it totally works. The code looks okay to me or am I missing something? If someone can shed light on this.

```
  jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    $('#player').on('input', function() {
      var searchKeyword = $(this).val();
        if (searchKeyword.length >= 2) {

        var vurl = '<?= get_template_directory_uri(); ?>';
         $.post('"+vurl+"/others/goals.php', { keywords: searchKeyword }, function(data)

                 {
                 $('ul#cf').empty()
                $.each(data, function(ding, dong) {
               $("ul#cf").append('<a><li id="'+ dong.id +'"> ' + dong.title+ '</li></a>');
               $('ul#cf').on('click','li',function(){
               $('#player').val(this.id);
                });
               });
             }, "json");
            }
        });
    });
```

Answer (score 2):

Correct code :

```
$.post(vurl+'/others/goals.php',  ...
```

Comment: Correct, thought he was missing the echo before the function call for the URI but he's used the shorthand "<?="

Comment: For some strange reason it continues to not work. Replacing var with url works normally.  Very strange!

Comment: Maybe you have two slashes in your url (if vurl ended by /).
Insert console.log(vurl +'/others/goals.php'); just before $.post(... and check the browser console result.

Comment: Appreciate your suggestion. URL path seems to be working okay but it's showing GET 404 (no found) to this file wp-includes/js/jquery/jquery.js?ver=1.12.4